# Continuous maps from products of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces. It is well-known that if $F:X\times Y\to Z$ is a continuous map, we can define a map $$\overline{F}:X\to C(Y,Z) \\\overline{F}(x)(y)=F(x,y)$$ where $C(Y,Z)$ is the topological space of all continuous maps from $Y$ to $Z$ equipped with the compact-open topology, and this induced map is continuous.

If $Y$ is locally compact Hausdorff, the converse holds, i.e. if a function $\overline{F}:X\to C(Y,Z)$ is continuous, and related to $F$ by the equation above, then $F$ is also continuous. This converse seems a bit unsatisfying, so I was wondering:

> Does the converse also hold under some weaker assumptions? What is the best known theorem in this regard?

Also, I suspect the problem might be with the choice of topology on $C(Y,Z)$. As nice as the compact-open topology might be, I imagine there might be some other (more or less natural) choice of topology availible for which the continuity of $F$ and continuity of $\overline{F}$ would be equivalent.

> Does there exist such a topology?

Comment: Have a look at [this MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44358/compact-open-topology) answer and the refernces therein

Comment: Also Wikipedia has an entry that claims that $Y$ need by locally compact Hausdorff, but no reference: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the paper referenced in [the Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44358/compact-open-topology), the first line of the abstract states:

> It is well-known that a Hausdorﬀ space is exponentiable if and only if
>   it is locally compact, and that in this case the exponential topology is the
>   compact-open topology.

Comment: Thanks, the article you link answers pretty much everything I wanted to know (and more).